# Use Spring Model attribute to set js variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I'm Using Spring Boot and there is a point that I don't understand.
Suppose I have a `model`, created in a Controller's method, annotated with `@ResponseBody` annotation.
I must put, inside this model, 2 variables, a String and an int, that I have to use to set 2 global variables in a js file; this setting is done in case of ajax function success.

So, for semplicity, let's assume that my global variables are `global1` and `global2`; and that the variables to put inside model are `String a` and `int b`; in this scenario, what must happend is:

```
$.ajax({
        ...<url, method and other actions here>...
        success: function(){
                 global1 = String a;
                 global2 = int b;
        }
```

My doubt are 3:

1. How I may put the variables `String a` and `int b` inside the model? Should I use `model.addObject()` or it's better create a `Modelmap` object, fill this one with `a` and `b` and then put him inside the model? Which difference there is between this 2 approaches?
2. In the ajax function, when I have `success: function()`, which parameters should I give in input to `function()`?
3. Inside the success function, how can I use the model data to set the global variables? What syntax may I use to perform this? In other words, when I have my model, how can I access its variables and use to perform `global1 = String a` and `global2 = int b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Model` object and use `addAttribute` method for every object you need to have in ajax success function. In every Spring method you can add `Model` object, for example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="value", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String yourMethod(@RequestParam(value="yourParam") String yourParam,
                       Model model){
    String a = "Your String";
    int b = 456;

    model.addAttribute("myString", a);
    model.addAttribute("myInt", b);

    return "";
}
```

The success function must be declared with one parameter, that is the response. Inside this parameter you will find the parameters you added in model object (`myString` and `myInt`):

```
success: function(response){   
            // response.myString will be "Your String"
            // response.myInt will be 456
        }
```

Comment: this works perfectly. Thanks a lot, also for editing!

Answer (score 1):

General : The clean way is to use `$("form").serialize();` in data of AJAX it makes `param1=param1value&param2=param2value`
and take back using `@ModelAttribute className className` , however in edit you may have many problems such checkBox or date or radio buttons automatic value detecting  , so I recommend you to use spring form back-end and pass back end object and drop Ajax if you can!  Also using  @ResponseBody you should make json object in client side and get in server such `@RequestBody className className` , and I think json approach taking too time in client side for development , spring in client side specially in Ajax has not any ability , so for Ajax I prefer to use thymleaf fragment load instead of jquery AJAX , in this method you can even use Thymleaf object back command topography  .
But Your Questions 1-if you sending json use @RequestBody and get model such:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Car> update(@RequestBody Car car) {
    ...
}
```

@ResponseBody just supporting jackson automatic  backing object so you should just send back object , however you can send back status of ajax method using Response Entity it is wrapper that the data and status of html are in int such:

```
return new ResponseEntity<Car>(car, HttpStatus.OK);
```

or

```
 return new ResponseEntity("done", HttpStatus.OK);
```

2-if using jquery done function will got 200 201 and other success values
and done will acitvated you can get data by

```
.done(function(data) {
  alert( "$.get succeeded" ); });
```

3- In general come back data is list of json you should foreach and get each item as json object and open by point such `item.prop`